# How to solve sqlite cursor issue in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

Has anyone faced issue like?

Right now im using Sqlite DB for saving data in android.But im getting some issues like the below logcat,which is restricting and im unable to run my app.

suggestion please.

**LOGCAT**

```
06-04 12:03:05.603: E/Cursor(281): Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed. database = /data/data/org.twinkletech.postcourier/databases/GetNewsDetailsManager, table = null, query = SELECT  * FROM getnewsdetails
06-04 12:03:05.603: E/Cursor(281): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
06-04 12:03:05.603: E/Cursor(281):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.<init>(SQLiteCursor.java:210)
06-04 12:03:05.603: E/Cursor(281):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:53)
06-04 12:03:05.603: E/Cursor(281):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
06-04 12:03:05.603: E/Cursor(281):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1315)
06-04 12:03:05.603: E/Cursor(281):  at org.twinkletech.postcourier.DatabaseHandler.getAllContacts(DatabaseHandler.java:91)
06-04 12:03:05.603: E/Cursor(281):  at org.twinkletech.postcourier.Splash_Screen$Show_Default_News.Call_db_handler(Splash_Screen.java:133)
06-04 12:03:05.603: E/Cursor(281):  at org.twinkletech.postcourier.Splash_Screen$Show_Default_News.Call_Service(Splash_Screen.java:99)
06-04 12:03:05.603: E/Cursor(281):  at org.twinkletech.postcourier.Splash_Screen$Show_Default_News.doInBackground(Splash_Screen.java:62)
06-04 12:03:05.603: E/Cursor(281):  at org.twinkletech.postcourier.Splash_Screen$Show_Default_News.doInBackground(Splash_Screen.java:1)
06-04 12:03:05.603: E/Cursor(281):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
06-04 12:03:05.603: E/Cursor(281):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-04 12:03:05.603: E/Cursor(281):  at  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-04 12:03:05.603: E/Cursor(281):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
06-04 12:03:05.603: E/Cursor(281):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
06-04 12:03:05.603: E/Cursor(281):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
   String str_data = "On 14 November 1987, Tendulkar was selected to represent Mumbai in the Ranji Trophy, India's premier domestic First-class cricket tournament, for the 1987–88 season. However, he was not selected for the final eleven in any of the matches, though he was often used as a substitute fielder";

DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(Splash_Screen.this);

            // Inserting Contacts
            Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
            db.addContact(new NewsDetails(result_data));

            // Reading all contacts
            Log.d(">>--Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
            List<NewsDetails> contacts = db.getAllContacts();       

            for (NewsDetails cn : contacts) 
            {
            //  str_db_news = "Id: "+cn.getID()+" ,Name: " + cn.getName() ;
                String str_db_news = cn.getName();
                }
           }
```

**DatabaseHandler.java**

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "GetNewsDetailsManager";

// NewsDetails table name
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "getnewsdetails";

// NewsDetails Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String CREATE_NEWS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT"+ ")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_NEWS_TABLE);
}


// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

// Adding new contact
public void addContact(NewsDetails contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection

}

// Getting single contact
NewsDetails getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    NewsDetails contact = new NewsDetails(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1));
    // return contact
    return contact;
}

// Getting All Contacts
public List<NewsDetails> getAllContacts() {
    List<NewsDetails> newsdatalist = new ArrayList<NewsDetails>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            NewsDetails news_data = new NewsDetails();

//              contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            news_data.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
            news_data.setName(cursor.getString(1));

            // Adding contact to list
            newsdatalist.add(news_data);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    db.close(); // 


    return newsdatalist;
}

// Updating single contact
public int updateContact(NewsDetails contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
}

// Deleting single contact
public void deleteContact(NewsDetails contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    db.close();
}

// Getting contacts Count
public int getContactsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}}
```

**NewsDetails.java**

```
public class NewsDetails {

//private variables
int _id;
String _name;

// Empty constructor
public NewsDetails(){

}
// constructor
public NewsDetails(int id, String name){
    this._id = id;
    this._name = name;
}

// constructor
public NewsDetails(String name){
    this._name = name;
}
// getting ID
public int getID(){
    return this._id;
}

// setting id
public void setID(int id){
    this._id = id;
}

// getting name
public String getName(){
    return this._name;
}

// setting name
public void setName(String name){
    this._name = name;
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are missing to close the cursor in your db handling.

For example: In your `getContact` method, don't forget to call `cursor.close()` right before returning the value.

Comment: but im closing the cursor on getContactsCount().then why it is showing  the issue like this

Comment: bur im still getting the same issue...Can you plz help me to solve this error?

Comment: You need to close your **cursor** everywhere. I see you are missing this in `getAllContacts` method too.

Comment: you get the error because you close the cursor and then you try to get data from it again. once you close the cursor you cannot use it anymore

Comment: i've closed it,but still it is same:(

Comment: @prabu I just told you the problem

Comment: As @tyczj mentioned, once a cursor is closed, you should not further request any data from it. To resolve this, generate a new cursor and proceed.